# How to present JSON information in a html.erb file (Ruby)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby

I am new to Ruby/Rails and I've been given a task to make a Ruby site (.html.erb) look a bit nicer. One of the things requested was to present information on the site, which is currently shown as JSON, as nice-looking html. The line of html.erb is as follows:

`<%= @buyer.generate_profile.inspect %><br>`

and will display the information it receives on the site as JSON. What can I do to parse through the JSON and make it so that the site will display the information as proper html?

Comment: What is `@buyer.generate_profile`? What is "proper HTML", or "nice-looking HTML"? Your question at the moment is extremely vague; we know almost nothing about your data or what you're actually trying to achieve with it.

Comment: I'm going to try to explain more. The line provided presents this on the site: {:xx=>{:xx=>xx, :xx=>0.0, :xx=>0.0}, :xx=>{:xx=>0.0, :xx=>0.0, :xx=>0.0}, :xx=>{:xx=>0.0, :xx=>0.0, :xx=>0.0}, :xx=>0.0, :xx=>"xx"}. I put the xx's to hide confidential information. What I want to know, is how to make it so that it doesn't display a JSON, but rather something like this (line by line): xx: 0.0, and then on a new line, xx: 00, and this for every piece of information that it renders. Since this is my first time seeing this code, I'm going to say that @buyer.generate_profile shows info idk about inspect

Comment: Is there something like a "JSON.stringify" method?

Comment: JSON.pretty_generate? https://apidock.com/ruby/JSON/pretty_generate

Comment: Is `{:xx=>{:xx=>xx, :xx=>0.0, :xx=>0.0},.....` a **well-defined structure**, so you actually know what format the data will be in? If it is, then you could do all sorts of things to make "pretty HTML", you really just need to decide however you want it to look, and fetch the precise data accordingly! But if it's a mysterious chunk of JSON in an unknown structure, then there's not much more you can do besides `pretty_generate` or similar, and leave it as a blob of data on the page.

Comment: Note that `{:xx=>{:xx=>xx, ...` is **not JSON**. `@buyer.generate_profile` probably evaluates to a Ruby [Hash](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.2/Hash.html). You can loop through this with [`each`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.2/Hash.html#method-i-each), or you can use [square brackets](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.2/Hash.html#method-i-5B-5D) to access specific keys. `<% profile = @buyer.generate_profile %>` then `profile[:xx]` to access the `:xx` key.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out [`JSON.pretty_generate`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-3.0.0/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html#method-i-pretty_generate).  You could display the result in a `code` block like:

```
<%# If your data is a JSON string, convert it to a hash %>
<% hash = JSON.parse(@buyer.generate_profile) %>
<pre>
  <code>
    <%= JSON.pretty_generate(hash) %>
  </code>
</pre>
```

Comment: This will escape the json and will not render the actual json in the browser code

Answer (score 0):

So the `generate_profile` method returns a Hash object and calling `inspect` on it will create string output of the Hash syntax in Ruby, so the result looks like your comment.

If you wanted it to look like JSON, the simplest way would be to use the `to_json` method like this

```
<%= @buyer.generate_profile.to_json %>
```

but honestly, it's not much better. And even if you were to look into methods that can present it with proper line breaks, etc. that wouldn't improve it much either imo.

I would recommend you learn how to iterate over the keys and values in a Hash, because that would allow you to create a custom HTML layout that could look however you wanted it to.

As an example, I'll show you how you could create a simple table based on the data from your comment

```
<table>
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Key</th>
    <th>XX</th>
    <th>YY</th>
    <th>ZZ</th>    
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <% @buyer.generate_profile.each_pair do |key, sub_hash| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= key %></td>
      <td><%= sub_hash[:xx] %></td>
      <td><%= sub_hash[:yy] %></td>
      <td><%= sub_hash[:zz] %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The main thing here is the use of `each_pair` which is a method that iterates over each key and value of the hash. In your case it sounds like the values of the first hash are sub-hashes, hence my use of `sub_hash` as the block argument.

You could technically use `each_pair` on the sub-hashes as well, but I'm guessing they all have the same keys, that's why I manually added columns and cells for XX, YY, ZZ in combination with `sub_hash[:xx]`, etc.

Once you get a hang of how iterating over Hashes and arrays work, then I would recommend scrapping the table design and instead look into more modern web design approaches like Flex and CSS-Grid, but one thing at a time :)